# Printing an array from a loop

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to print out the array given by user input, so I decided to do this using a for loop. However, I noticed that I had trouble printing out the array once I'm done with the loop. Sorry if something doesn't make any sense when explaining, I'm new to java.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class activity2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String[] doubleArr = new String[5];
            System.out.print("Enter string " + i + ": ");
            doubleArr[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The desired out that I am aiming for is:

```
Enter string 1: Hey
Enter string 2: There
Enter string 3: Yall
Enter string 4: Good
Enter string 5: Bye
Your array:
Hey There Yall Good Bye
```

Comment: Am I able to set a global variable? Then add that array in the loop not sure.

Comment: It's a 2 step thing. You did the first: read the input. Now, you have to do the loop again, but printing the output instead of reading the input.

Comment: You need to move the declaration of your array, `String[] doubleArr = new String[5];`, to OUTSIDE and BEFORE the loop that populates it.  Then you (presumably) need another loop to iterate over that array and output its contents.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class activity2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] arrayOne;
        arrayOne = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter string " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            arrayOne[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        int arrayOneLength = arrayOne.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOneLength; j++) {
            System.out.print(arrayOne[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just figured it